# what does int() on a number starting with 0 do?

Tags: python-2.7, int

The following two lines will both print out 12:

> print int(12)
>   print int("012")

Why does the following print 10?

> print int(012)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you're happy with the answer please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an [octal (base 8)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) numeric literal, which is supported in Python 2 natively (though confusingly) along with hexadecimal (e.g. `0x1C`). However, all numbers are *printed* by default in decimal, so you're getting the *decimal* (base 10) version of that integer returned to you:

```
(1 * 8) + (2 * 1) = 10
```

#### Python 2 output

```
$ python2 -c "print 012"
10
```

#### Python 3

Note in [Python 3 this has changed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/#removal-of-old-octal-syntax):

```
$ python3 -c "print(010)"
  File "<string>", line 1
    print(010)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```